# UICollectionView wrong image displayed

Tags: uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, tvos

I've found a couple of posts about issues with UICollectionView and iwrong images but all of them have one common - people try to download image in cellForItemAt method. 
I already have proper image in my app bundle and simply use UIImage(named:) method to set it to UICollectionViewCell. However I still get wrong images. Could anyone help me?

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return liveChannels.count()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ChannelButtonViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ChannelButtonViewCell


        let current = liveChannels.channels[indexPath.row]
        let currentProgram = current.currentProgram()

        let channelKey = current.channel?.channelKey
        let programDetail = currentProgram?.name

        if let currentProgress = currentProgram?.progress() {
            cell.progressView.setProgress(currentProgress, animated: true)
        }

        print("\(channelKey) - \(current.channel!.logoName)")
        cell.imageName = current.channel!.logoName
        cell.channelTitleLabel.text = channelKey
        cell.channelDetailLabel.text = programDetail

        cell.channelButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ChannelsViewController.pressed(_:)), for: .primaryActionTriggered)
        return cell
    }
```

I'm printing channelKey and logoName to console to be sure that the proper image is stored inside of liveChannels.channels structure. (THey are correct indeed).

This is my cell:

```
class ChannelButtonViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var progressView: UIProgressView!
    @IBOutlet weak var channelButton: ChannelButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var channelDetailLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var channelTitleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var channelImageView: UIImageView!
    var imageName: String?

    override func prepareForReuse() {

        channelImageView.image = nil

        super.prepareForReuse()
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        if (self.isSelected) {
            if let imageName  = imageName {
                channelImageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
            }

        } else {
            if let imageName  = imageName {
                channelImageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName.appending("_grey"))
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You should override `func draw(_ rect: CGRect)` in very rare cases and your case is definitely not the one.

2) To ensure you load and change image *exactly* when you assign cell's `var imageName: String?` you could use Swift's `didSet`

3) To ensure your image updates when selection state changes you could use `didSet` as well.

you could end up removing func `draw` at all and adding `didSet` observers like this:

```
class ChannelButtonViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var progressView: UIProgressView!
    @IBOutlet weak var channelButton: ChannelButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var channelDetailLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var channelTitleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var channelImageView: UIImageView!
    var imageName: String? {
        didSet {
            updateImage()
        }
    }

    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            updateImage()
        }
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        channelImageView.image = nil
        super.prepareForReuse()
    }

    func updateImage() {
        guard let imageName = self.imageName else { return }
        if (self.isSelected) {
            channelImageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        } else {
            channelImageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName.appending("_grey"))
        }
    }

}
```

If this solution doesn't solve your problem try set breakpoint inside of `func draw()` and check when it is called and what value stored in `var imageName`

Comment: Hi,it looks like didSet make the difference, however I had to leave draw method there, because I didn't find another way how to change images based on isSelected status. Do you have any idea where to put it for better results?